# I'm getting 0 results but the record is in the DB

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

My python code runs on an XML file and checks if all the references are in the DB (MySQL DB).
when the product is not in the DB, the output will be "product doesn't exist in DB"
the checking process is in the python code:

```
                str_sql = "select id_product from ps_product where reference = '" + makat + "';"
                str_sql = str_sql.replace('"\"', "")
                productID = get_productId(str_sql)
                if (productID == 'error' or productID == 'None'):
                    errorReason = "product don't exsits in DB"
                    print("error: product don't exsits in DB -  ", productName,", ",makat)
```

for example, the desired reference is F0FB0056IV.
the reference has a record in DB table ps_product , but still, I'm getting 0 results.

why?

Comment: *for example, the desired reference is F0FB0056IV. the reference has a record in DB table ps_product , but still, I'm getting 0 results.* Does this query returns record(s): `"select id_product from ps_product where reference = 'F0FB0056IV';"`?

Comment: Yes It does ...in phpmyadmin, but not in python

Comment: *but not in python* If so then show complete python code which tries to execute this query.

Comment: `code` 
str_sql = "select id_product from ps_product where reference = '" + makat + "';"
str_sql = str_sql.replace('"\"', "")
productID = get_productId(str_sql)
`code`